# Get access to php variable in Joomlas addscriptdeclaration for Javascript

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, javascript, variable

How do I get access to php variables in Joomlas approach to integrate Javascripts with addScriptDeclaration?

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$variable = "test";

$document->addScriptDeclaration('
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        var simple = "<?php echo $variable; ?>";
        alert(simple);
    });
);
```

The classic form of integrating php variables won't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instantly see the issue here.
What you basically doing is the following:

```
<?php    
    $var = 'foo';
    <?php echo $foo; ?>    
?>
```

You're using duplicate `<?php` tags which will cause issues.

Use the following instead

```
<?php
    $document = JFactory::getDocument();
    $variable = "test";

    $document->addScriptDeclaration('
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            var simple = "' . $variable . '";
            alert(simple);
        });
    ');
?>
```

You were also missing a closing single quote before the last bracket in your code which I've added for you.

Answer (score -2):

This is how you can get access to php variable inside javascript.

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$variable = "test";

$document->addScriptDeclaration('
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        var simple =<?php echo json_encode($variable); ?>;
        alert(simple);
    });
);
```

Comment: You don't use `<?php echo json_encode($variable); ?>` inside `<?php` tags that are already there. `$document = ` is already PHP, not Javascript. See my answer to get a better understanding